# Identify the port on which request is made by client of REQ-REP ZeroMQ application,server is bound to two endpoints(port number)?

Tags: c++, server, port, zeromq

The server is bound to two sockets on port#s: **`6666`** ( to service an SMS send request from client ) and **`6661`** ( to service an EMAIL send request from client ).

Since I want to service them differently, I must first know on which port the request has come, so that I can execute a code for that service.

So, my question is how can I identify the port?

If this is not possible, then what logic can be applied to solve this problem?

The server side code is :

```
int main () {

zmq::context_t context (1);               // Prepare our context and socket

zmq::socket_t socket  (context, ZMQ_REP); socket.bind  ("tcp://*:6666");
zmq::socket_t socket2 (context, ZMQ_REP); socket2.bind ("tcp://*:6661");

while (true) {      
  // ----------------------------------SMS CODE----------------------------------
     zmq::message_t request;
     socket.recv ( &request);             // Wait for next request from client

  /* ...                                  // SMS Send Logic
     ...
                                          */
     zmq::message_t reply (11);           // Send reply back to client
     memcpy (reply.data (), "SMS Details", 11);
     socket.send (reply);

  // --------------------------------EMAIL CODE----------------------------------
     zmq::message_t request2;
     socket2.recv (&request2);            // Wait for next request from client

  /* ...                                  // Email Send Logic
     ...                           
                                          */
     zmq::message_t reply2 (16);          // Send reply back to client
     memcpy (reply2.data (), "Email Details", 16);
     socket2.send (reply2);
  }                                       // end of while
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [zmq::poll](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-poll) to check which sockets have pending messages before attempting to read from them. There is an official cpp example [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:mspoller).

You can also use ZMQ_DONTWAIT to check for messages, but you should still poll to avoid using too much CPU.

example:

```
#include "zeromq.hpp"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    zmq::context_t context(1);

    zmq::socket_t emailSocket  (context, ZMQ_REP); emailSocket.bind  ("tcp://*:6666");
    zmq::socket_t smsSocket (context, ZMQ_REP); smsSocket.bind ("tcp://*:6661");

    //  Initialize poll set
    zmq::pollitem_t items [] = {
        { emailSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
        { smsSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
    };
    //  Process messages from both sockets
    while (1) {
        zmq::message_t message;
        // wait until there is a message ready for one of the sockets
        zmq::poll (&items [0], 2, -1);

        // try to read/process a message from email socket (Don't wait, just skip if there are none)
        if (emailSocket.recv(&message, ZMQ_DONTWAIT)) {
            //  Process email request
            zmq::message_t response(...);
            emailSocket.send(&response);
        }
        // same again for sms socket
        if (smsSocket.recv(&message, ZMQ_DONTWAIT)) {
            //  Process sms request
            zmq::message_t response(...);
            smsSocket.send(&response);
        }
        // back to the top of the loop to wait for another message
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I read the man page of zmq_poll. From what I understood, When we run this server code , when poll function is called it will wait indefinately till event occurs on either of the two sockets. Am  I right? Can you please explain what will happen next. Suppose if Sms request is received then? When will if condition expression will be executed.

Comment: The c++ socket call `bool socket_t::recv(message_t *msg, int flags = 0)` returns true if it successfully receives a message (see docs http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-cpp)

Comment: You are right about poll. If an sms request is received, then poll will return, and the program continues. Then you try to read from the email socket, but there is nothing, so `.recv()` returns false, and you skip it. Then you try to read from the sms socket, which succeeds, so you process the sms request.

Comment: But it is given in the docs that two receives cannot be executed consecutively. Doc Ref-"The REQ-REP socket pair is in lockstep. The client issues zmq_send() and then zmq_recv(), in a loop (or once if that's all it needs). Doing any other sequence (e.g., sending two messages in a row) will result in a return code of -1 from the send or recv call. Similarly, the service issues zmq_recv() and then zmq_send() in that order, as often as it needs to."

Comment: So after the emailSocket.recv executes and returns false (incase sms request is received) , executing smsSocket.recv should not be valid.

Comment: if it returns false, then it didnt receive, so its safe to try again

Comment: also, that is true only for one socket at a time, i.e. you need to receive one message, then send a reply for that socket. You can't receive two requests on the same socket, then send replies, or send two replies to one request.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's demystify the problem and clean the code

The code is principally wrong and will not compile ( check the non-matching curl-brace there ).

Next your code does not match your text explanation ( check the swapped port-numbers text says 6666 is for emails, while the code implements this one for SMS handling ).

Finally, even the corrected code is not very robust against falling into a mutual and principally un-salvageable deadlock.

---

### Yet, the question asks for detecting a port number.

Given the assigned port-numbers in both the **`.bind()`**-methods have mapped the pair of ZeroMQ-`socket` instances disjunctively onto different port#-s, there are no doubts upon a message arrival, from which socket-instance `{ socket | socket2 }` such a message has arrived.

Given this, there will all SMS-designated messages come from port **`6666`**.

Given this, there will all MAIL-designated messages come from port **`6661`** ( unless some sender-side intended sabotage has taken place, but this goes beyond the scope of the question ).

> My question was how will we selectively run the SMS or EMAIL code depending on the port number on which the request comes [from comments]

**Negative**, your question was formulated "***how can I identify the port?***" - i.e. how to detect a port#, while your code was principally wrong, both in its syntax and in its semantic design.

> Syntax errors removed. I understand that the code enters deadlock. And that can be avoided by running the either SMS or EMAIL code depending on the port on which the request comes. [from comments]

**Negative**, your code design proposed to use an imperative pure-`[SERIAL]` schedule to enter a blocking-wait-state upon first expecting a read from SMS-ingress access port#:**`6666`** and if and only if this indeed happens in some time in the future ( which is never guaranteed to ever indeed happen ), the code may then step into the next ( again blocking ) wait-state and remains waiting until some ( if any ) EMAIL-ingress message would ( hopefully ) ever arrive.

> You wrote " there are no doubts upon a message arrival, from which socket-instance { socket | socket2 } such a message has arrived." How do you get to know on which port the request arrived **(code please)**, so that accordingly we can serve it [from comments]

---

### ( Code please )

If you have moved the question from "how can I identify the port?", kindly start with re-reading the ZeroMQ API documentation about using **`poll()`** and get your job done correctly.

Comment: My question was how will we selectively run the SMS or EMAIL code depending on the port number on which the request comes.@user3666197

Comment: Syntax errors removed. I understand that the code enters deadlock. And that can be avoided by running the either SMS or  EMAIL code depending on the port on which the request comes.

Comment: You wrote " there are no doubts upon a message arrival, from which socket-instance { socket | socket2 } such a message has arrived." How do you get to know on which port the request arrived (code please), so that accordingly we can serve it

Comment: It's easier to answer the question than to type out this tirade